# log4cxx logger modification in docker container

Tags: docker, log4cxx

I have a c++ application that uses log4cxx for logging. log4cxx configuration will be done via XML file where the logging level and different loggers can be enabled and disabled. with installation running in VM it was easy to make the necessary modifications as needed by getting into VM and changing the XML file manually. but now we are going to run the application as a docker image which will run in the cloud, so the question is how to make modifications around the logger level as and when needed. I did try to search for this before asking here, but the solutions which are mentioned are java based, like spring boot admin, etc. which is not suitable here.

Comment: Pardon me for asking, but what does this have to do with C++? You're basically asking how to ripple configuration file changes into a docker image instance running in some container in the cloud. That the code relying on those configuration changes happens to have been authored in C++ seems irrelevant.

Comment: Hello, log4cxx is for c++ code, so i tagged it with c++. is it wrong?

Comment: I understand. My point was that the root of your problem seems to be in conveying configuration file changes into a running docker container. In your non-container  environment I assume you were using the periodic log4cxx configure-and-watch mechanics to periodically rescan the config and update the running environment as needed, correct? If so, then the root problem seems to be how to upload configuration changes to the container, which is a docker/container 'thing', not necessarily a c++ thing.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes you are right. let me edit the code and remove c++ tag